# Pasando proyecto de VB.NET a c# con problemas

Tags: c#, vb.net

estoy intentando pasa los proyectos que tengo de VB.NET a c# y dado el archivo **"MyNamespace.Static.1.Designer.cs"** Al pasar el código vi que utilizaba todavía la librería "Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices" es decir en el inicio decía "Using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;" y lo que quiero es dejar de utilizar los servicios de compilación de Visual Basic
A continuación el archivo como es, Convertido el código, pero sin dicha librería, Quisiera saber como puedo yo reemplazarla utilizando alguna librería nativa de C#

El archivo por ejemplo tiene la siguiente clase
internal partial class MyApplication :

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ConsoleApplicationBase
    {

    }
```

Luego la siguiente es:

```
internal partial class MyComputer : Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer
    {
        
        [DebuggerHidden()]
        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public MyComputer() : base()
        {
        }
    }
```

El código completo está aquí https://pastebin.pl/view/fc50b6a6

Alguien sabe como reemplazarlo? he intentado hacer un proyecto nuevo y este archivo no se crea.

Comment: Y que hace esa libreria nativa en Visual Basic?

Comment: Realmente no se, pues lo que ví lleva la escritura del diseño del proyecto, asumo que al haber una librería extra el proyecto tarda más en compuse, además de ocupar más espacio

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822